# django views - get values of ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a polling app with a ManytoMany Field in the Poll model.

I wanted to retrieve the values of the choice(ManyToMany) field in the views.

**models.py**

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    choice= models.ManyToManyField(Choice)

def __unicode__(self):
  return smart_unicode(self.question)

class Choice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="img")
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def __unicode__(self):
  return smart_unicode(self.name)
```

**views.py**
There are 2 choices in each poll and I want to assign each of these choices to 2 separate variables but do not know how to.

```
def polling(request)
    try:
        choices = Poll.objects.all()
        choice_1 = **assign 1st ManyToMany Field value** 
        choice_2 = **assign 2nd ManyToMany Field value**
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, I'd imagine

```
def polling(request):
    for poll in Poll.objects.all():
        choice_1 = poll.choice.all()[0]
        choice_2 = poll.choice.all()[1]
```

or

```
def polling(request):
    for poll in Poll.objects.all():
        for choice in poll.choice.all():
            # Do something with choice
```

Note: If each poll object always has exactly 2 choices, you might as well use foreignkeys instead

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    choice_one = models.ForeignField(Choice)
    choice_two = models.ForeignField(Choice)
```

That way, it won't need a third table to keep track of relationships between choices and polls, which in turn would be more efficient.

Finally, you should take a look at django documentation, that does a great job at explaining all of this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1):

A small change to the Dellkan's solution..as at the end choice_1 and choice_2 would be of the last entry of poll in the loop

```
polldict={}
def polling(request):
    for poll in Poll.objects.all():
        index=poll.id
        choicedict={}
        choicedict['choice_1'] = poll.choice.all()[0]
        choicedict['choice_2'] = poll.choice.all()[1]
        polldict[index]=choicedict
```

Use this if the poll entries are not large enough..Later you can access the choice with

```
polldict[id]['choice_1']
```

Not a big stuff but a small logic to workaround with various polls and options.